# implement method with ref qualifier

Tags: c++, c++11

I have trouble to implement following code

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    std::vector<T> vec;

    std::vector<T> getVector() && {
        // fill vector if empty
        // and some other work
        return std::move(vec);
    }

    std::vector<T> getVectorAndMore() &&
    {
        // do some more work
        //return getVector(); // not compile
        return std::move(*this).getVector(); // seems wrong to me
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;

    auto vec = std::move(foo).getVectorAndMore();
}
```

The problem is that I can't call `getVector` inside `getVectorAndMore` because `this` is not rvalue. To make the code compile, I had to cast `this` to rvalue.

Is any good way to implement such code?

---

with `return getVector();`

error message is

```
main.cpp:17:16: error: cannot initialize object parameter of type 'Foo<int>' with an expression of type 'Foo<int>'
        return getVector(); // not compile
               ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:26:31: note: in instantiation of member function 'Foo<int>::getVectorAndMore' requested here
    auto vec = std::move(foo).getVectorAndMore();
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23aa6a4a4e8d07c4)

Comment: BTW, this code compiles fine (with `Clang 3.4`): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/911ce206d19eea5c

Comment: @Nawaz I mean this version http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23aa6a4a4e8d07c4 . I know what is the error, I know why it failed, I know how to workaround it, I am asking a better way to fix it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
return getVector(); // not compile
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
return this->getVector(); // not compile
```

which wouldn't compile, because `this` is an lvalue, not an rvalue and `getVector()` can be invoked only on rvalue, hence the error.

**Note that `this` is *always* an lvalue — even inside rvalue-ref member function!**

---

```
return std::move(*this).getVector();
```

That is the correct way to invoke `getVector()`.

Comment: so you are saying there is no better way?

Comment: Um, is it similar to *perfect forwarding*?

Comment: @ikh: I don't know what you meant by "similar". It is definitely not "same" as perfect forwarding. Perfect forwarding is more like forward the arguments as they're, without changing their *value category* (whatever they're).

Comment: `this` is a prvalue. `*this` is an lvalue.